# React - Mapping through response data from get request-why response data is not displayed?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Im new to react and I am trying to display response data I get from an get request.I have been looking at multiple similar posts, trying to implement what worked for others, but for me nothing works. In my code below, Im not getting any errors (set state seems to work too) but nothing is being displayed and I don't know why. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
        class Testing extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    name: []
                };
                this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                this.getData();
            }
            getData() {
                axios.get('https://example.com)
                    .then(results => {
                        return results.data;
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        let arr = res.items;
                        let test = [];
                        return arr.map(function(item) {
                            test.push(item);
                        })
                        this.setState({
                            name: test
                        });
                    })
                }

                render() {
                    const persons = this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
                        return 
                           <div>
                              <h1> {item.name} </h1> 
                           </div>
                    });

                    return 
                    <div id = "layout-content" className = "layout-content-wrapper" >
                        <div className = "panel-list"> 
                            All: {persons} 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

changed render:

```
 class Testing extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    name: []
                };
                this.getData = this.getData.bind(this)
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                axios.get('https://example.com)
                    .then(results => {
                        return results.data;
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        let arr = res.items;
                        let test = [];
                        return arr.map(function(item) {
                            test.push(item);
                        })
                        this.setState({
                            name: test
                        });

                    })
                }


                render() {
                    <div>
                       this.state.name ? this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
                           return (
                              <div>
                                <h1>{ item.name }</h1>
                              </div>
                           )
                       }) : null;
                    </div>

                }
            }
```

error here:

```
<div>
  this.state.name ? this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
   return (
        ^
        <div>
          <h1>{ item.name }</h1>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your setState is never called. If you look at your last then function of your api call, you have return statement right before the setState (i.e. at arr.map). Because of that your code never reaches the setState. Remove the return statement and it should work:

```
             getData() {
                axios.get('https://example.com)
                    .then(results => {
                        return results.data;
                    })
                    .then(res => {
                        let arr = res.items;
                        let test = [];
                        arr.map(function(item) {
                            test.push(item);
                        })
                        this.setState({
                            name: test
                        });
                    })
                }
```

Edit:: Ok try wrapping your render in brackets `()` like this

```
               render() {
                    const persons = this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
                        return 
                           (<div>
                              <h1> {item.name} </h1> 
                           </div>);
                    });

                    return 
                     (<div id = "layout-content" className = "layout-content-wrapper" >
                        <div className = "panel-list"> 
                            All: {persons} 
                        </div> 
                    </div>);
                }
```

Comment: thank you. I tried out your solution but still-nothing is being displayed. I think the problem is with my render function?!

Comment: I dont think there is any problem with your rendor function in your first code snippet. Are you sure your data is coming from api?

Comment: This render function in my answer is correct. I myself have tested it. If there is an array in this.state.name then it will display correct output. It means somehow your api output is not setting the state. You tried it after removing return from your arr.map, right?

Comment: Try console.log right above this.setState and see the data in test array.

Comment: Okay so I console.log (item)  from the array Im mapping through and get: Object{country:"US", id:"1", name:"example"}Object{country:"US", id:"1", name:"example"}... or console.log(test) and get [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: Thank you. I just copy pasted your code and just changed the parts where I am making the api request etc and it all works now. I went through every line of code because I couldn't understand whats different and it turns out (which i didn't know, I guess its a react syntax thing?!) when you out the parentheses below the return keyword it doesn't work like it has to come right after return like return(

Comment: Is that really a react thing?!

Comment: Also, I get the warning:Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop so I added <h1 key={item.id}> {item.name} </h1> or <h1 key={i}> {item.name} </h1> but Im still getting the error. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: You have to put "key" at first element. In your case that is div not h1. So put key at div.

Comment: That is not react thing. I think it is the thing related to babel. Because babel is transpiling this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you forgot to add a single quote inside the get request like this     `axios.get('https://example.com')`

your code:

```
axios.get('https://example.com')
  .then(results => {
     return results.data;
  });
```

Comment: you must never forget to close a string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, move your `getData` function or even whole request logic into `componentWillMount` function. Secondly, change your `render` function into:

```
render() {
   return (
   <div>
      this.state.name ? this.state.name.map((item, i) => {
          return (
             <div>
               <h1>{ item.name }</h1>
             </div>
          )
      }) : null;
   </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. When I changed the render function (please see edit) im getting an error:SyntaxError: Unexpected token (it seems that there is something wrong with the return because thats what im getting the error for)

Comment: @javascripting Your code formatting is invalid. Look at my answer code and then look at your code.

Comment: oh didn't see it (formatted it with some code formatter and thats what came out).changed it. the error is in the edit.

Comment: @javascripting Seems like you miss `return` keyword in the `render` function.

Comment: i just copy pasted your solution which has a return keyword which throws the error or what do you mean?

Comment: @javascripting The `render` function **also** has to return something. Look at my code.

Comment: I look at your code, but your code which I used throws me the error.

Comment: But there's no `return` in your `render` function. **render**, not **map**.

Comment: then how would you do it??

Comment: Just replace your whole `render` function with mine. That's all.

Comment: Again, I already replaced my whole render function with yours. it is in the edit!!

Comment: @javascripting Are you having fun? You didn't change your `changed render` code :-)